# Estimability in Design model

Tags: regression, estimation, blue

consider the design model  **$y=\theta+e$**

I know we can obtain the normal equations from observation to estimate the parameters. my question is- is the estimation BLUE?
Given normal equations are:

$y_1=\theta_1+ \theta_2+\theta_3$
$y_2=\theta_1- \theta_2+\theta_3$
$y_3=\theta_1          +\theta_3$
$y_4=\theta_2$

Estimates:

$\theta_2=y_4$
$\theta_1+\theta_3=(y_1+y_2)/2$
$\theta_2=y_3-y_2$

Is these estimates are blue?

Comment: That depends on the properties/behavior of the errors, which are not specified here.

Comment: Can You say anything now? estimates are not unique. Is this the reason for not being BLUE?